# Least squares regression coefficient with minimal information

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression, least-squares, regression-coefficients, sample-size

If I only have a correlation matrix of 4 variables and the sample size, is it possible to predict 1 variables from the other 3 while using information about sample size? I’m trying to use lm but my degrees of freedom are 0 because I’m unable to incorporate the sample size information somehow. Can anyone help?

Comment: If you mean the R function `lm` will not be possible. Regression coefficients cannot be calculated only from the correlation matrix (but you **can** get the coefficients for the regression based on the *standardized variables*, though. For the coefficients for regression based on original variables you will need also means and variances. Why don't you have access to full dataset? explain, and some more details.

Comment: Is there any chance that you mean covariance matrix rather than correlation matrix?

Answer (score 0):

If all you have is a correlation matrix and $N$, then you *are* able to create simulated data but not much else. To do this, make a $N \times 4$ matrix $Z$ consisting of random standard normals. Then calculate the square root of your correlation matrix $R$ using Cholesky decomposition. The matrix  $X=ZR^{1/2}$ will correspond to 4 variables in the standardized form that @kjetil is referring to in his comment. That is as far as we can go without means and standard deviations.